# Отправка пользователю сообщения ботом

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пишу простенького бота, подскажите, как его дописать таким образом, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку консультация, он отправлял любое рандомное сообщение конкретному пользователю?
Пробовал

```
bot.send_message(id юзера, 'текст')
```

Но он возвращает ошибку

```
Threaded polling exception: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found
```

Вот код бота:

````
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('6542913554:AAEPRwpdyTMc499Egpqc1j38jYCU-zLA2G4')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Меню")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Консультация")
    markup.add(item1, item2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Что вас интересует?", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_level(message):
    if message.text == "Меню":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Наши преимущества")
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Процесс услуги")
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Стоимость услуги")
        item4 = types.KeyboardButton("Сделать самому")
        item5 = types.KeyboardButton("Консультация")

        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Меню:", reply_markup=markup)
    if message.text == "Наши преимущества":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "преимущества:", reply_markup=markup)
    if message.text == "Процесс услуги":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "процесс:", reply_markup=markup)
    if message.text == "Стоимость услуги":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Стоимость:", reply_markup=markup)
    if message.text == "Сделать самому":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Сделать:", reply_markup=markup)
    elif message.text == "Консультация":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Консультация", reply_markup=markup)


bot.polling()```
````

Comment: Бот не может писать первым. Если юзер еще не взаимодействовал с ботами, то ему сообщение не отправить.